# How launch app after short push on hardware search button?

Tags: java, android, search

How launch app after short push on hardware search button? What the code need for manifest.xml ?

Repeat: not for long search, like this: android.intent.action.SEARCH_LONG_PRESS, only after short push.
Please install Tasker and you will see how this works...

Comment: Hardware search button was removed in Icecream sandwich so only gingerbread and lower have it. Do you really want to focus on this narrow market?

Comment: search buttons (2 types google search widget & app and softKeyboard search button) There is an intent called ActionSearch and for softkeyboard there is IME_OPTIONS_SEARCH or something similar